# “Dual object” as set of irreps of a finite group

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, terminology, duality-theorems

In Barry Simon's [*Representations of finite and compact groups*](https://doi.org/10.1090/gsm/010) he refers to the set of irreps (or rather equivalence classes thereof) of a given finite group $G$ as the “dual object” $\widehat G$

> **Definition** $\widehat G$, the dual object, is the set of equivalence classes of irreps, each class consisting of unitarily equivalent irreps. (p. 25)

I can't seem to find this terminology being used anywhere else, but in what sense is this duality meant? What structure warranting invocation of “duality” does the dual object have besides its cardinality equalling the number of conjugacy classes?

Comment: Maybe $\widehat G$ is the set of linear characters of $G$? It makes sense calling it dual, since the linear characters of $G$ are the homomorphisms $G\to\mathbb C^*$. Also, I have read papers where the symbol $\widehat G$ denotes the set of linear characters of $G$. But in this case, its cardinality is $|G:G'|$, which is not the number of conjugacy classes unless $G$ is abelian.

Comment: Simon uses $\widehat G_1 \cong \widehat{G/[G,G]}$ to denote the linear characters, and notes that if $G$ is abelian then $\widehat G = \widehat G_1$ is called the dual group (with pointwise multiplication). At any rate, $\widehat G$ is pretty explicitly defined as the set of all irreps, not just one-dimensional ones.

Comment: There is some variation in convention and terminology. The dual group (aka character group, which over $\Bbb Q$ coincides with the notion of dual vector space) generalizes to the set of irreps, which is justification enough to call it a "dual object" informally, if not formally. More formal justification might be via Fourier transform (functions on $G$ vs. matrix coefficients), or arguably the correct duality for finite groups is via conjugacy classes and irreps ([link](https://mathoverflow.net/a/102894/508777)).